# An unexpected error occurred: Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle' [Hardhat, openzeppelin]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, openzeppelin, hardhat, binance-smart-chain

I keep getting this error when doing: npx hardhat run scripts/sample-script.js --network testnet. Edited the name of my computer for security reasons. How do I put in the module 'nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'?

```
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'
Require stack:
- /Users/Secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /hardhat.config.js
- /Users/Secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/config/config-loading.js
- /Users/Secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sarhangsaid/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /hardhat.config.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/Secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /hardhat.config.js',
    '/Users/Secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/internal/core/config/config-loading.js',
    '/Users/Secret/Documents/Code 2 - Hardhat /node_modules/hardhat/internal/cli/cli.js'
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you're running at least npm 8.5.2

Comment: In my case had to install `@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle` and `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@^2.0.0`. The second one was suggested by npm itself

Answer (score 8):

The problem could be that you have not installed the hardhat waffle package. You should do:

```bash
npm install -D @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle
```

then edit the `hardhat.config.js` file and add

```js
require('nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle');
```

above the `module.exports` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is from [Patrck Collins's solidity course](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=30636).

We need to delete the unwanted config file.

1. Find it

```bash
  npx hardhat --verbose
```

```bash
  hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /Users/hardhat.config.js
```

2. Then Remove it

```bash
rm /Users/hardhat.config.js
```

Try`yarn hardhat` again, it worked for me.

Comment: Following along the same course I got the exact same error.
The cause was that i had autocompleted to the incorrect require in hardhat.config.js:

@nomicfoundation/hardhat-etherscan (Wrong)
@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan (Correct)

Answer (score 0):

you lack the @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle package in your dev folder. use yarn or npm to install it as a dev dependency, then modify the config file accordingly.