# Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'

Tags: hardhat

My reputation isn't high enough for answering, so I thought I would post the answer here.
This answer is from [Patrck Collins's solidity course](https://youtu.be/gyMwXuJrbJQ?t=30636).

We need to delete the unwanted config file.

1. Find it

```bash
  npx hardhat --verbose
```

```bash
  hardhat:core:config Loading Hardhat config from /Users/hardhat.config.js
```

2. Then Remove it

```
rm /Users/hardhat.config.js
```

Try `yarn hardhat` again, it worked for me.

Comment: This is the question you wanted to answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115021/an-unexpected-error-occurred-error-cannot-find-module-nomiclabs-hardhat-waff.